# How to add feature based limit in second generation package scratch org?

Tags: second-generation-packaging, feature-management

I am trying to develop a second generation package with a scratch org, I need to add feature based limit parameters, however since scratch org in second gen package don't have the actual package, I can't access it's UI, here is what it look like in my package UI:

[image]

And here is where I am suppose to add it:

[image]

How can I add it without the UI?  Is it possible to define it somewhere in the SFDX code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create them in your metadata.

[FeatureParameterBoolean](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_featureparameterboolean.htm), [FeatureParameterDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_featureparameterdate.htm), and [FeatureParameterInteger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_featureparameterinteger.htm) are the relevant file types, which you can include just like you would any other type of metadata that's supported. You can also view the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage) for more information.